# Find the first matching word from a vector in a string column

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I need to know which of the words in a vector comes first in a string. I need to run this code on a large data frame with millions of records.

df is my sample data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
Text = c("A basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches",
"A basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches",
"A basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples"))
```

The words I am looking to match are in a vector

```
vec <- c("green bananas", "apples", "peaches")
```

I want a result column for each record like this

```
df$Result 
"apples", "green bananas", "peaches"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regmatches` + `regexpr` like below

```
transform(
    df,
    Result = regmatches(Text, regexpr(paste0(vec, collapse = "|"), Text))
)
```

or `str_extract`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Result = str_extract(Text, paste0(vec, collapse = "|")))
```

which gives

```
  ID                                                         Text        Result
1  1 A basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches        apples
2  2 A basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches green bananas
3  3 A basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples       peaches
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted. Did not realize it would come down to just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the first match, see ThomasIsCoding's solution. If you want all matches and if you want to make sure your matches do not indavertently match unwanted stuff, such as, for example the word "dapple", which happens to contain the word "apple", here's a solution that takes care of both issues, by using `str_extract_all` and by using word  boundary anchors `\\b`

```
df %>%
  mutate(Matches = str_extract_all(Text, str_c("\\b(", vec, collapse = "|", ")\\b")))
  ID                                                         Text                        Matches
1  1 A basket of fruits having apples, green bananas, and peaches apples, green bananas, peaches
2  2 A basket of fruits having green bananas, apples, and peaches green bananas, apples, peaches
3  3 A basket of fruits having peaches, green bananas, and apples peaches, green bananas, apples
```

Comment: Indeed. Than you for the comment. I have added the boundary anchors.